Double clicking on folders from Desktop screen open in Disk Usage Analyzer rather than in Files
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 (Wayland, GNOME 46), and currently, when I try to open a folder from the home screen, it opens in the Disk Analyzer app rather than the Files app. This happens every time, and I have to open the Files app each time and navigate to that folder. I have a few folders on the desktop home page of my laptop, and it's happening for every folder. Could someone assist me with this?
Here are some pictures for demonstration:
This is my home screen:

When I double-click on a folder, this is what happens:

As you can see, instead of opening in Files, it's opening in the Disk Analyzer app.

Install nautilus via and reboot :
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop

Had the same issue and it fixed it for me.

Tried it doesn't work :(
